# ffmpeg complains about incorrect parameters

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi there I am trying to convert a wave file to mp3 with ffmpeg and I get the following error messages. Could anyone perhaps give me a hint as to what the potential problem might be? thank you!

```
FFmpeg version git-7ed4ff0, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct 31 2015 08:02:55 with gcc 4.6.4
configuration: --prefix=/srv/current/stack --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libvpx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pic --enable-shared
libavutil 50. 37. 0 / 50. 37. 0
libavcore 0. 16. 1 / 0. 16. 1
libavcodec 52.112. 1 / 52.112. 1
libavformat 52. 99. 1 / 52. 99. 1
libavdevice 52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
libavfilter 1. 75. 0 / 1. 75. 0
libswscale 0. 12. 0 / 0. 12. 0
[wav @ 0xaa8560] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, wav, from '/srv/shared/tmp/upload/upload_1747a42a8869bc9927a2e4a7d2f65368.WAV':
Duration: 00:01:03.06, bitrate: 3456 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 3 channels, s32, 3456 kb/s
Incompatible sample format 's32' for codec 'libmp3lame', auto-selecting format 's16'
Output #0, mp3, to '/srv/shared/tmp/scratch/05f12c018e4411e59e55c364c14dbce0':
Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 3 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

EDIT:
Hi there, forgot to put the command that triggered the error, here it is:

```
nice ffmpeg-v1.0.0  -i /srv/shared/tmp/upload/upload_dd34711f1164d4499bb0d4d36ae4462d.wav -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128000 -f mp3 -vn /srv/shared/tmp/scratch/65e3ba218f1011e59350073ba02f8ea7
```

Comment: Could you include the command line that produced that output?

Comment: Please test a build from current git master (try a [static build](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)) and provide a link to the input file. FFmpeg development is very active, and attempting to provide help for such an old build would be a waste of everyones time.

Answer (score 0):

## The problems

- libmp3lame only supports mono and stereo channel layouts, but your input has 3 channels. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libmp3lame`.
- Your `ffmpeg` appears to be ancient and is too old to be supported. Also, the git hash `7ed4ff0` does not appear to refer to any commit in the master branch, so your build may have derived from a fork.

## Solutions

First, get a build made from recent git master. Downloading a [static build of `ffmpeg` for Linux](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) is an easy method. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for options for Windows and OS X.

Then choose how you want to deal with the extra channel. The lazy method would be to downmix to stereo by adding the `-ac 2`, or mono with `-ac 1`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) if you want more control or do not want to include the extra channel.